# How to pass the result of a function that calculates the transpose of a matrix to another function that prints the matrix?

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, parameter-passing, transpose

I have created two functions, one that finds the transpose of a function and another that prints it. I know the printMatrix function works fine.
However I do not know how to transpose the matrix using a function, then print it.

```
int main()
{
  //Constants
  int givenMatrix[3][3];

  //Takes in the given values of the matrix
  cout << "Please input matrix values in the order described " <<endl;
  for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i){
    cout << "Eneter Three Elements for Row: " << i + 1 << endl;
    for (int j=0; j < 3; ++j){
      cin >> givenMatrix[i][j];
    }
  }

printMatrix(givenMatrix);
int p = indexTranspose(givenMatrix);
printMatrix(p);
//pointerTranspose(givenMatrix);

return 0;
}
```

This is the function where I find the Transpose of Matrix

```
//Function to find the transpose using indices     
void indexTranspose(int givenMatrix[3][3]){
  int transpose[3][3];

  //Find the transpose of the matrix
  for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
    for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
    transpose[i][j] = givenMatrix[j][i];
    }
  }
}
```

Also I tried to find the transpose of the matrix via pointers but failed, if possible can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
//Function to find the transpose using indices
void pointerTranspose(int givenMatrix[3][3])
{

    //Find the transpose of the matrix
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
      for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
      *(*transpose[j][i]) = *(*givenMatrix[i][j]);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is for a homework problem, I recommend asking the teacher for some help, because there are a few parts of your question that would indicate that you've misunderstood some topics. Without knowing where your coming from it would be difficult for me to do a good job of correcting those misunderstandings.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is indeed a homework. Sadly, I can't make his office hours. The professor asked to create an 3x3 matrix that is read through the keyboard in main. Then create a void printMatrix() function that will print any matrix when called, and also a void transposeMatrix() function. We also had to use the printMatrix() function to output the new transposed matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I do not know how to print the transpose of a function using
>   the printMatrix function.

There is a bit packed into that statement, but it looks like you are asking "How would I pass the `transpose` function as an argument to the `printMatrix` function so that the `printMatrix` function prints the transpose of the matrix (or will print any other variation of the matrix based on the function I pass it).

Essentially, if that is what you are after, you are simply wanting to pass a function that will manipulate your matrix in some way as an argument, and then have the print function apply that function and then print the results. In essence it is the same as creating the transpose the matrix and then passing the transposed matrix as a single argument to `printMatrix`, but by being able to change the behavior of `printMatrix` by including another argument that does something to the matrix before it is printed has merit.

Regardless of whether you create the transpose first and pass that, or you pass the original matrix and the transpose function, you will need a second matrix to hold the transpose of the orginal so its values can be printed. The key difference will be within what scope the transpose matrix needs to be visible. From the point of your `indexTranspose` function it doesn't matter. You have two options (1) you leave the return type `void` and pass in a second matrix to be filled with the transpose of the original, or (2) you change the return type of the `indexTranspose` function and dynamically allocate for the matrix to hold the transpose and return a pointer to it.

(**note:** as extensions to both you can pass a reference to an existing matrix, or declare and return a STL container, but those will be left for another day as you are using a 2D array of fundamental type `int`)

The simplest, is simply passing in another 3x3 2D array to hold the transpose values. You can simply add another parameter to your `indexTranspose` function to accomplish this, e.g.

```
 /* Function to find the transpose using indices */     
void indexTranspose (int (*transpose)[3], int (*givenMatrix)[3])
{
    //Find the transpose of the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            transpose[i][j] = givenMatrix[j][i];
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** whether you pass `int transpose[][3]` or `int (*transpose)[3]` they are equivalent. When you pass an array as an argument to a function, the first level of indirection is converted to a pointer to the first element -- in this case *a pointer to array of `int` [3]*. The second form above showing the explicit result of the conversion)

If you want to pass `indexTranspose` as an argument to `printMatrix`, you have to understand what the type for the function pointer would be. In its full form the type for `indexTranspose` is:

```
void (*f)(int (*)[3], int (*)[3]);
```

(a function pointer `f` with return type `void` that takes two *pointer to array of `int` [3]*, e.g. two 3x3 2D arrays, as its arguments)

So adding the function pointer as an argument to your `printMatrix` function could be:

```
void printMatrix (int (*m)[3], void (*f)(int (*)[3], int (*)[3]))
{
    int altered[3][3] = {{0}};

    f (altered, m);  /* apply function to original m, with results in altered */

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            std::cout << " " << std::setw(3) << altered[i][j];
        std::cout.put ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Note:** here is where the scope of the second matrix to hold the results of applying the function to the first become important. Since you are only using the result to print, the second matrix (called `altered` above) can be declared local to your `printMatrix` function for the purpose of printing. So above, your `printMatrix` function now takes the original matrix `m` and a pointer to a function that returns `void` and accepts two 3x3 2D integer matrices as its parameters and it updates the value of the 1st 3x3 2D array with the result of the transpose operation (or whatever operation the function will perform)

Then in your calling function (`main()` here), to pass the original matrix to `printMatrix` along with a pointer to `indexTranspose` and have the transpose occur in `printMatrix` and then output, all you would need to do is call:

```
    printMatrix (givenMatrix, indexTranspose);
```

Realistically, you would simply pass the altered matrix as the matrix parameter to `printMatrix` as you will presumably be using that matrix for more than printing, but it is a perfectly legitimate exercise to learn how to pass a function to provide the manipulation as well (as you will presumably be passing that function to something other than a print-function in the future)

Putting it all together, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

/* Function to find the transpose using indices */     
void indexTranspose (int (*transpose)[3], int (*givenMatrix)[3])
{
    //Find the transpose of the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            transpose[i][j] = givenMatrix[j][i];
        }
    }
}

void printMatrix (int (*m)[3], void (*f)(int (*)[3], int (*)[3]))
{
    int altered[3][3] = {{0}};

    f (altered, m);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            std::cout << " " << std::setw(3) << altered[i][j];
        std::cout.put ('\n');
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int givenMatrix[3][3];

    std::cout << "Please input matrix values in the order described " << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << "Eneter Three Elements for Row: " << i + 1 << '\n';
        for (int j=0; j < 3; ++j){
            if (!(std::cin >> givenMatrix[i][j])) {  /* always VALIDATE input */
                std::cerr << "error: invalid integer input.\n";
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    /* pass given & pointer to function */
    printMatrix (givenMatrix, indexTranspose); 
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/prn_mtrx_by_fn
Please input matrix values in the order described
Eneter Three Elements for Row: 1
1 2 3
Eneter Three Elements for Row: 2
4 5 6
Eneter Three Elements for Row: 3
7 8 9
   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9
```

Let me know if you have any further questions about passing a function pointer as an argument, or if I misinterpreted your question, let me know as well, I'm happy to help further.

Answer (score 0):

First I'll explain why your original function didn't work. The array you create in indexTranspose is a local variable, meaning it doesn't exist outside of the function. So, when `indexTranspose` finishes, and your program returns to `main`, transpose is gone.

You were on the right path trying to use pointers, but didn't get it quite right.

You need to have pointerTranspose accept a pointer to your 3x3 matrix. It looks like you were trying to make givenMatrix a pointer after you've already created it, you can't do that. Here is an example of pointerTranspose that works:

```
//Function to find the transpose using indices
void pointerTranspose(int (*givenMatrix)[3][3])
{
    int transpose[3][3];
    //Find the transpose of the matrix
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            transpose[i][j] = (*givenMatrix)[j][i];
        }
    }

    //Set the values in the original matrix
    for (int i=0; i < 3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < 3; j++){
            (*givenMatrix)[i][j] = transpose[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would call it like this: `pointerTranspose(&givenMatrix);`

You could also do this without creating the temporary `transpose` variable inside `pointerTranspose` by assigning `(*givenMatrix)[j][i]` directly to `(*givenMatrix)[i][j]` but I'll leave that as an exercise for you. (Hint: be careful you don't swap things twice!)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I will try your exercise, however can you clarify why I would need the //Set the Values in the original matrix part?

Comment: For the same reason your original `indexTranspose` function didn't work. The line `transpose[i][j] = (*givenMatrix)[j][i];` is reading from givenMatrix, and writing to transpose. After the "Find the transpose of the matrix" part, the `transpose` variable holds the transpose, but `givenMatrix` is unchanged. Since `transpose` is a local variable, it is destroyed at the end of the function, and you loose all of that work.